# Add plpython3 Extension to Postgres/timescaledb Alpine Docker Image

Tags: postgresql, docker, alpine-linux, plpython, timescaledb

I try to add the `plpython3` extension to my `timescaledb`/`postgres` (based on linux alpine) image:

```
FROM timescale/timescaledb:0.9.0-pg10

RUN set -ex \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .plpython3-deps --repository http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing \
    postgresql-plpython3
```

When I try to create the extension I get the following error:

```
postgres=# CREATE EXTENSION plpython3u;
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/local/share/postgresql/extension/plpython3u.control": No such file or directory
```

But when I search for the files inside my container I can find them within a different directory:

```
/ # find / -name '*plpy*'
/usr/lib/postgresql/plpython3.so
/usr/share/postgresql/extension/plpython3u.control
/usr/share/postgresql/extension/plpython3u--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/extension/plpython3u--unpackaged--1.0.sql
```

How can I install `postgresql-plpython3` to a different directory or configure `postgres` to recognize my added extension?

**Update**

When I just `mv` the files to `/usr/local/share/postgresql/extension` I get the error:

```
postgres=# CREATE EXTENSION plpython3u;
ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/plpython3": No such file or directory
```

**Update 2**

So the issue with `$libdir` was that `pg_config --pkglibdir` points to `/usr/local/lib/postgresql` but `plpython3.so` is inside `/usr/lib/postgresql`. When I move everything to the according `/usr/local` directories I can successfully create the extension.

This leads to the question where I hope to find an answer. How can I install `postgresql-plpython3` to `/usr/local/...` instead of `/usr/...`?

Comment: try one of them in your dockerfile  COPY pg_config /usr/local/bin/pg_config

RUN chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/pg_config

#using try it
# RUN  sed -i '/PKGLIBDIR = /usr/local/lib/postgresql/c\/PKGLIBDIR = /usr/share/postgresql' /usr/local/bin/pg_config
#second option create semi link
# RUN  ln -s /usr/share/postgresql/extension/plpython3u.control /usr/local/share/postgresql/extension/plpython3u.control

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am fairly certain that if you use prebuilt packages you are stuck with hardcoded installation paths.

The easiest way around your problem is to create symlinks after installation:

```
FROM timescale/timescaledb:0.9.0-pg10

RUN set -ex \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .plpython3-deps --repository http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing \
    postgresql-plpython3 \
    && ln -s /usr/lib/postgresql/plpython3.so /usr/local/lib/postgresql/plpython3.so \
    && ln -s /usr/share/postgresql/extension/plpython3u.control /usr/local/share/postgresql/extension/plpython3u.control \
    && ln -s /usr/share/postgresql/extension/plpython3u--1.0.sql /usr/local/share/postgresql/extension/plpython3u--1.0.sql \
    && ln -s /usr/share/postgresql/extension/plpython3u--unpackaged--1.0.sql /usr/local/share/postgresql/extension/plpython3u--unpackaged--1.0.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

Just configure your `postgresql.conf` to load the extension shared libraries from the expected path.

```
plpython3u.library_path = '/usr/lib'
```