# PostgreSQL on Docker: How to install and run python dependencies under `plpython3u`?

Tags: python, postgresql, docker

With `Dockerfile` I can run `plpython3u` perfectly

```
FROM postgres:11.3

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y postgresql-plpython3-11
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION return_version()
  RETURNS VARCHAR
AS $$
    import sys
    return sys.version
$$ LANGUAGE plpython3u;
```

> 3.5.3 (default, Jul  9 2020, 13:00:10)
> [GCC 6.3.0 20170516]`

But I can't use dependencies for example `requests`

```
[38000] ERROR: ImportError: No module named 'requests' 
Where: Traceback (most recent call last): PL/Python function "return_version", line 3, 
in <module> import requests PL/Python function "return_version"
```

1st Attempt to do a `call`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION return_pip()
RETURNS VARCHAR AS $$
from subprocess import call
return call(["pip", "install", "requests"])
$$ LANGUAGE plpython3u STABLE ;
```

No hope

```
[38000] ERROR: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pip' Where: Traceback (most recent call last): PL/Python function "return_ls", line 3, in <module> return call(["pip", "install", "requuest"]) PL/Python function "return_ls", line 246, in c ...
```

2nd Attempt

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION return_version()
  RETURNS VARCHAR
AS $$
    import sys
    from subprocess import call
    return call(["pip3", "install", "requests"])

    import requests
    res = requests.get('https://google.com')
    print(res.text)
    return res.text
$$ LANGUAGE plpython3u;
```

Got error

```
SELECT return_version()
[2020-09-29 10:59:44] [38000] ERROR: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pip3'
[2020-09-29 10:59:44] Where: Traceback (most recent call last):
[2020-09-29 10:59:44] PL/Python function "return_version", line 4, in <module>
[2020-09-29 10:59:44] return call(["pip3", "install", "requests"])
[2020-09-29 10:59:44] PL/Python function "return_version", line 246, in call
[2020-09-29 10:59:44] PL/Python function "return_version", line 675, in __init__
[2020-09-29 10:59:44] PL/Python function "return_version", line 1281, in _execute_child
[2020-09-29 10:59:44] PL/Python function "return_version"
```

I got similar person asking same question, but no [answer](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAG2HOmgh2obkE7mxqDe75jSbNLAFNqgsjKnPVL9W9niOemjE4w%40mail.gmail.com)

**Question:**
How to install and run python dependencies under `plpython3u`?

Comment: Is `requests` installed for Python 3 in the container? FYI, in your `CALL` example `requests` is spelled wrong.

Comment: Don't you need to use `pip3`, not `pip`, to install for python3?  Maybe that depends on your OS and how you installed python.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thanks for correct my typo, but problem still persist

Comment: @jjanes Not work, you can check my error msg

Comment: You didn't answer the first question,  is `requests` installed for Python 3 in the Docker container?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver No, it isn't. Give me a shot one moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @AdrianKlaver for his answer

Follow this. I can get the `response`

1. I pick this answer to be my [image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49379401/add-plpython3-extension-to-postgres-timescaledb-alpine-docker-image)
2. Execute `CREATE EXTENSION plpython3u;` in SQL shell
3. Run `pip3 install requests` In OS(aka container)
4. create function

   ```sql
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION return_version()
      RETURNS VARCHAR
   AS $$
    import requests
    res = requests.get('https://google.com')
    return str(res.text)
   $$ LANGUAGE plpython3u;
   ```
5. `SELECT return_version();` Check the result