# Cannot create Python language in Postgres under Alpine linux

Tags: postgresql, alpine-linux

I am trying to install Python3 language into my Dockerized postgres 10.16

```
bash-5.1# apk add postgresql-plpython3
(1/3) Installing libffi (3.3-r2)
(2/3) Installing python3 (3.8.10-r0)
(3/3) Installing postgresql-plpython3 (13.3-r0)
Executing busybox-1.32.1-r6.trigger
OK: 373 MiB in 105 packages
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM mdillon/postgis:10
ADD ./scripts/tune-postgis.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

I've had to follow [Add plpython3 Extension to Postgres/timescaledb Alpine Docker Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49379401/add-plpython3-extension-to-postgres-timescaledb-alpine-docker-image) which made the postgres find the files, but then I get **symbol not found SPI_commit**

```
gis=# CREATE EXTENSION plpython3u;
ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/local/lib/postgresql/plpython3.so": Error relocating /usr/local/lib/postgresql/plpython3.so: SPI_commit: symbol not found
```

Google has not found such an error message, can you please help?

Comment: I have similar problem, have you manage to find a solution?